# Jquery get all checked checkboxes values in form submission

Tags: jquery

Thanks in advance NINJAS. 
This is driving me nuts. I can't find how to loop through and GET all checked checkboxes from my form submission. It is only retrieving one value.

Jquery

```
    var price_range = jQuery(".et_pb input[type=checkbox]:checked").val();
```

HTML

```
                        <span class="et_pb">
                        <span class="field_options_title">Desired Price Range</span>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_0" class="input" value="Under $200,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_0"><i></i>Under $200,000</label>


                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_1" class="input" value="$200,000 - $300,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_1"><i></i>$200,000 - $300,000</label>


                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_2" class="input" value="$300,000 - $400,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_2"><i></i>$300,000 - $400,000</label>


                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_3" class="input" value="$400,000 - $500,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_3"><i></i>$400,000 - $500,000</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_4" class="input" value="$500,000+" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_4"><i></i>$500,000+</label>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested only in values you can use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```js
var price_range = jQuery(".et_pb input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(idx, ele) {
    return ele.value.indexOf('500') > -1 ? '4' : ele.value;
}).get();


console.log(price_range);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="et_pb">
    <span class="field_options_title">Desired Price Range</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_0" class="input" value="Under $200,000" data-id="" data-value="1" checked>
    <label for="price_range_12_0"><i></i>Under $200,000</label>


    <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_1" class="input" value="$200,000 - $300,000" data-value="2" data-id="">
    <label for="price_range_12_1"><i></i>$200,000 - $300,000</label>


    <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_2" class="input" value="$300,000 - $400,000" data-id="" data-value="3" checked>
    <label for="price_range_12_2"><i></i>$300,000 - $400,000</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_3" class="input" value="$400,000 - $500,000" data-id="" data-value="4" checked>
    <label for="price_range_12_3"><i></i>$400,000 - $500,000</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_4" class="input" value="$500,000+" data-value="5" data-id="">
    <label for="price_range_12_4"><i></i>$500,000+</label>
</span>
```

Comment: I tried alert(price_range); but it came up empty ??

Comment: This works great! Anyway to change the "value" when it is select and submitted ? So if $500,000 was selected, can we change the value to equal "4" ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample in the above snippet ?

Comment: So I would have to add a "data-value" in the form?

Comment: I am not able to do that .. The divi wordpress contact form is limited..

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` to get all values

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var a=[];
$('input').change(function(){

$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    a.push($(this).val());
    console.log(a)
});
})



})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="et_pb">
                        <span class="field_options_title">Desired Price Range</span>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_0" class="input" value="Under $200,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_0"><i></i>Under $200,000</label>


                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_1" class="input" value="$200,000 - $300,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_1"><i></i>$200,000 - $300,000</label>


                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_2" class="input" value="$300,000 - $400,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_2"><i></i>$300,000 - $400,000</label>


                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_3" class="input" value="$400,000 - $500,000" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_3"><i></i>$400,000 - $500,000</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="price_range_12_4" class="input" value="$500,000+" data-id="">
                        <label for="price_range_12_4"><i></i>$500,000+</label>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hobbies= [];
        
$.each($("input[name='favlist']:checked"),function(){
    hobbies.push($(this).val());
});

alert(hobbies);

 <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="favlist">
 <input type="checkbox" value="tenis" name="favlist">
```